# How do I switch between swipe and pan in Unity in one touch?

Tags: unity

I am trying to create a gesture handler that can detect both swipes/pans - within one touch - in Unity. I should be able, within one touch event, to pan slowly to the left or right. During the same touch, without lifting my finger, I should be able to then swipe to the left or right. How do I do this? Here is my code below.

`````
private void Update() {

if (Touch.activeFingers.Count == 1)
        {
            swipeAllowed = true;
            var touch = Touch.activeTouches[0];

            // all collected touches must be converted to screen -> world point to be used in calculations

            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            {
                startPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.screenPosition);
                StartCoroutine(CheckForAnimation(touch));
            }

            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Stationary) 
            {
                DragAndDrop(touch);
            }

            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
            {
                Debug.Log("moved");
                currentPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.screenPosition);
                StartCoroutine(DragOrSwipeCamera(startPos, currentPos, touch));
            }
       }
}

IEnumerator DragCamera(Vector3 startPos, Vector3 currentPos, Touch touch)
    {
        distance = currentPos - startPos;
        var velocity = (float) (Vector3.Distance(currentPos, startPos) / (touch.time - touch.startTime));

        // PSEUDOCODE: Based on velocity, decide whether it should be a drag or a swipe? Not sure what to do here?
        
        yield return null;
    }
````
`````

Comment: This looks like a rephrasing of [your previous question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/202099/39518) - did you mean to edit your existing question rather than posting a new one? If not, can you clarify how this question differs? What do you define to be the difference between a pan and a swipe?

Comment: I've now deleted that post. There is a subtle difference, in that I realized that the real question here is that swipe/drag need to occur at the same time and that velocity can then be determined by the acceleration involved?

Comment: If I'm understanding your goal correctly, I think you might be making a false dichotomy here, and that you just want drag with momentum on release, and a magnification of movement for fast dragging. So there's no separation between swipe and drag, it's just one mechanic that can be used in different ways depending on the speed of the input.

Comment: I see. That's correct - I want: a) momentum on release of a drag in the correct direction, and b) I want the "drag" to be read as a swipe, so momentum only, if it is fast enough. I just don't know how to structure this code.

Comment: I think you should try not to make a distinction between drag and swipe - that's going to confuse your work. There's just dragging. At low speed, when the touch moves 1 pixel, you move the camera 1 pixel. At high speed, you increase that multiplier, so when the touch moves 10 pixels, you move the camera 15 pixels, or something like that. Just adding a scale factor that's a function of (smothed) speed should be enough.

Comment: So would this require me to calculate velocity between frames? Or would I try to see how quickly it has moved in a specified amount of time and then see how much I would add?